# Use Mysql function as column name in select query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table with columns for each day of months. e.g., 1,2,3,4.. are column name. i want to select particular day column based on day present in emp.date.

I tried following query but it is not working.

```
SELECT emp.id
     , emp.DATE_FORMAT(emp.date, "%d") 
  FROM emp_pattern_mapping epm 
 WHERE epm.year = 2019
   AND epm.month = 8
   AND epm.type = 2
   AND epm.emp_id = 39;
```

It is giving column not found error

Comment: Define "not working".  Is there an error?  An unexpected result?  Something else?

Comment: @David it is giving column not found error. As it is considering `DATE_FORMAT(emp.date,"%d")` AS sring

Comment: Instead of using `emp.DATE_FORMAT(emp.date, "%d")` just use `DATE_FORMAT(emp.date, "%d")`, without the `emp.`

Answer (score 1):

You have a very poor data format and you should devote your effort to fixing it.

You can do what you want with a giant `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT `emp`.`id`,
       (CASE WHEN DAY(emp.date) = 1 THEN `1`
             WHEN DAY(emp.date) = 2 THEN `2`
             . . .
             WHEN DAY(emp.date) = 31 THEN `31`
        END)
FROM emp_pattern_mapping epm
WHERE epm.year = 2019 AND
      epm.month = '08' AND
      epm.type = 2 AND
      epm.emp_id = 39;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT `emp`.`id`,DAY(emp.date) as emp_day
FROM emp_pattern_mapping epm
WHERE epm.year = 2019 AND
      epm.month = '08' AND
      epm.type = 2 AND
      epm.emp_id = 39;
```

Comment: I want to use it as column.. in this way i will only get the value of day present in date.

Comment: You can use `HAVING` with `emp_day` alias

Comment: How can we use HAVING to select a field